# Data received when downloading file from Google Drive API is incorrect

Tags: android, kotlin, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive API to backup my android app Data similar to Whatsapp. I write the data from several files (eg. db, and other misc) onto a single binary file and upload it to drive. But when I download the same file to restore the data, the bytes towards the end of the downloaded file are not the same as that uploaded. Any idea why this could be?

My Code

Backup

```
backupFile.outputStream().use { outputStream ->
            // Write File 1 data
            file1.inputStream().use {
                val data = it.readBytes()
                outputStream.write(data.size)
                outputStream.write(data)
            }

            // Write File 2 data
            file2.inputStream().use {
                val data = it.readBytes()
                outputStream.write(data.size))
                outputStream.write(data)
            }

            // Write File 3 data
            file3.inputStream().use {
                val data = it.readBytes()
                outputStream.write(data.size)
                outputStream.write(data)
            }
        }
```

Restore

```
dataInputStream.use { inputStream ->
            // Read File 1 Data
            file1.outputStream().use {
                val size = inputStream.read()
                val data = ByteArray(size)
                inputStream.read(data)
                it.write(data)
            }

            // Read File 2 Data
            file2.outputStream().use {
                val size = inputStream.read()
                val data = ByteArray(size)
                inputStream.read(data)
                it.write(data)
            }

            // Read File 3 Data
            file3.outputStream().use {
                val size = inputStream.read()
                val data = ByteArray(size)
                inputStream.read(data)
                it.write(data)
            }
        }
```

When I try it this way, the size value I get in the last `read()` call for **File 3** returns some ridiculously large value which leads a `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

My Drive Code

Upload

```
suspend fun uploadBackupFile(file: File) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val gFile = com.google.api.services.drive.model.File().apply {
            name = file.name
            parents = backupParents // String With Drive Spaces
        }
        val fileContent = FileContent(BACKUP_MIME_TYPE, file) // MIME TYPE is application/octet-stream

        val createdFile = getDriveService().Files().create(gFile, fileContent).execute()
```

Download

```
suspend fun downloadBackupFile(fileId: String): InputStream = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        getDriveService()
            .Files()
            .get(fileId)
            .executeMediaAsInputStream()
    }
```

The `InputStream` returned from `downloadBackupFile()` is what I read the data from when restoring

Comment: `inputStream.read(data)` Check the return value of read(). Probably its different from what you expect.

Comment: Have you checked the file sizes of the first two files?

Comment: @blackapps Yes the 2nd file has a size of around 49,472 bytes, but `inputStream.read(data)` is returning only 16,651 bytes as being read. Is it because the size is too big? What could be causing such a partial read?

Comment: That is pretty normal behaviour. That is why you should check the amount of bytes actually read. And make a loop until all bytes are read. Pretty normal to make a loop.

Comment: I haven't heard any mention of such an issue ever before. Learnt something new.

Comment: .read() returns an integer. Always check return values. .write() is void. It will write all bytes asked for. (It will use a loop doing so ;-)).